# Quando mudar uma célula no Excel (onChange) iniciar um contador no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Olá, gostaria de saber se no Excel ao mudar um valor em uma célula, por exemplo, na célula A1 está escrito "Falso" se alterando esse valor para "Verdadeiro", automaticamente iniciaria um contador e ele só zera quando o valor da A1 for pra "Falso de novo". Gostaria de saber se é possível isso, no Excel com VBA

Comment: Salve, meu caro! Coloque o código do que você já fez, e as pessoas podem ajudar com eventual erro.

Comment: Ai que tá não consegui fazer nada! Fui tentando fazer um contador padrão mas não funcionou ai apaguei o código

Comment: Tente de novo e coloque o código aqui. Se você não colocar um código, dificilmente vai conseguir ajuda. Um paradigma bem estabelecido é que o SO não é um site para encomendar código, e sim para ajudar os desenvolvedores com os bugs ou problemas nos códigos que eles têm.